# how to make PuTTY Customized color

Tags: putty

i am using **PuTTY** with GNS3.

i want to make my own background and font colors.

PuTTY have four themes. but i want to make Green background with black font.

so how to do that?

Comment: Please add much more detail. SuperUser is not here to tell you step for step how to do things which you can easily find with a google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the 'Window' section
2. From there, look for the 'Colours' page
3. At the bottom, you can select a RGB color for what you want to change.

Link: http://www.siue.edu/~dbock/cmis565/PuTTYColorSettings.htm

Comment: i have tried that . but it doesn't work .
i am forced forced to use one of the fours themes colors .
i think PuTTY with GNS3 is different than PuTTy in real world .